# Setting merge options to NotBuffered before a parallel ForAll query

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, plinq

Is it useless to a set merge options to NotBuffered before a ForAll call. Are these two snippet equivalent:

```
pquery.WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered).ForAll(DoStuff);
```

and

```
pquery.ForAll(DoStuff);
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to know this?

Comment: yes: (1)remove the redundant call; (2) have a better understanding on how PLINQ and PFX in general work.